# iOS - Which iOS devices support long range Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm wondering which iOS devices provide long range Bluetooth support (range of up to 800 feet). I assumed that long range Bluetooth support came from Bluetooth 5.0 (so any device higher than an iPhone 8), but I'm told that's not the case? Clarification would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that iPhones above the 8 have long-range Bluetooth. Bluetooth 5 is fully backward compatible with prior versions of Bluetooth as well.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I thought so - do you have a link to any Apple documentation confirming this?

Comment: I just checked- but no. I did call Apple to confirm this though!